# How to refactor a verbose datatype?

Tags: c#, algorithm, object-oriented

This morning I decided to write this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11727571/are-there-problems-if-i-have-a-verbose-datatype/11727723#11727723

I don't really explain my scenario about how am I accesing through the nested dictionaries. I decided to have the default alias (`IDictionary<string, IDictionary<Levels, IList<Problem>>>`) but I'm thinking that's not a good option right now.

I'm gonna show some parts of my code:

ProblemBaseFactory

```
public abstract class ProblemBaseFactory : IProblemFactory
{
    private IDictionary<string, IDictionary<Levels, IList<Problem>>> problemDictionaryPackages;

    protected ProblemBaseFactory()
    {
        problemDictionaryPackages = new Dictionary<string, IDictionary<Levels, IList<Problem>>>();
    }

    protected IDictionary<string, IDictionary<Levels, IList<Problem>>> ProblemDictionaryPackages
    {
        get { return problemDictionaryPackages; }
    }

    public abstract IEnumerable<Levels> AvailableLevels(string packageName);
    public abstract IEnumerable<Problem> LoadProblems(ProblemFactoryProperties properties);
}
```

RuleProblemFactory

```
public abstract class RuleProblemFactory : ProblemBaseFactory
{
    private IDictionary<string, IDictionary<Levels, IList<ProblemRule>>> ruleDictionaryPackages;
    private IRuleAlgorithmSelector ruleAlgorithmSelector;
    private IList<Problem> temp;

    protected RuleProblemFactory()
        : this(new Dictionary<string, IDictionary<Levels, IList<ProblemRule>>>(), new SequentialRuleSelector())
    {
    }

    protected RuleProblemFactory(IRuleAlgorithmSelector ruleAlgorithmSelector)
        : this(new Dictionary<string, IDictionary<Levels, IList<ProblemRule>>>(), ruleAlgorithmSelector)
    {
    }

    protected RuleProblemFactory(IDictionary<string, IDictionary<Levels, IList<ProblemRule>>> ruleDictionary,
        IRuleAlgorithmSelector ruleAlgorithmSelector)
    {
        this.ruleDictionaryPackages = ruleDictionary;
        this.ruleAlgorithmSelector = ruleAlgorithmSelector;

        LoadBankOfRules();
    }

    protected IDictionary<string, IDictionary<Levels, IList<ProblemRule>>> RuleDictionaryPackages
    {
        get { return ruleDictionaryPackages; }
    }

    public override IEnumerable<Problem> LoadProblems(ProblemFactoryProperties properties)
    {
        // does exist the package name?
        if (!ProblemDictionaryPackages.ContainsKey(properties.NamePackage))
            throw new InvalidOperationException("namePackage");

        IDictionary<Levels, IList<Problem>> problemPackage = this.ProblemDictionaryPackages[properties.NamePackage];

        // does exist the list
        if (!problemPackage.ContainsKey(properties.Difficulty))
            problemPackage.Add(properties.Difficulty, new List<Problem>());

        temp = problemPackage[properties.Difficulty];

        if (temp.Count >= properties.Quantity)
            return temp;
        else
            return GenerateProblems(properties);
    }

    private IEnumerable<Problem> GenerateProblems(ProblemFactoryProperties properties)
    {

        ruleAlgorithmSelector.Rules = ruleDictionaryPackages[properties.NamePackage][properties.Difficulty];

        ...
    }

    public override IEnumerable<Levels> AvailableLevels(string name)
    {
        return ruleDictionaryPackages[name].Keys;
    }
}
```

Sometimes I guess is difficult to readability. What do you recomend me to to mantain a better readability?

Comment: For readabilitiy I prefer the curly brackets in conditions and loops, one place I saw you could use var. I dont mind the `nested IDictionary`'s, if you did wrap them up in another class would that abstraction yield any benefit in your scenario?

Answer (score 2):

`IDictionary<string, IDictionary<Levels, IList<ProblemRule>>>` is difficult to understand and maintain. I don't know enough about your problem domain to give you reasonably sounding names for classes, but I'll try.

In your `LoadProblems` method, I see you set the `IDictionary<Levels, IList<ProblemRule>>` to a variable named `problemPackage`, so I would create a class `ProblemPackage`, containing a list of ProblemRules per Level (I would drop the 's' in Levels) and move the related logic there.

In `ProblemBaseFactory` you end up with a `IDictionary<string, ProblemPackage>`. `ProblemPackage` will have a `IDictionary<Level, ProblemRules>` and the class `ProblemRules` will be an easy wrapper around a `IList<ProblemRule>`.

If you try to delegate the work to these classes, the readability will almost certainly go up.